# Error trying to create trigger in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER historyTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON Item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if NEW.LocationId <=> OLD.LocationId or NEW.PersonId <=> OLD.PersonId THEN
insert into History values(null, old.Id, old.LocationId, new.LocationId, old.PersonId, new.PersonId, date(now()));
END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

which worked correctly on my database.

However, when I try to create this same trigger in phpMyAdmin, I get a syntax error (*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... near line 1*) [image]

**Edit:**

Having seen some other questions and examples online, and following the advice in the comments, I only left the body of my trigger:

```
if NEW.LocationId <=> OLD.LocationId or NEW.PersonId <=> OLD.PersonId THEN
insert into history values(null, old.Id, old.LocationId, new.LocationId, old.PersonId, new.PersonId, date(now()));
```

but I am still getting the same error, at line 2.

Comment: Remove a lot of the code - you just need the contents of the trigger (the if bit).  phpmyadmin adds in the logic around the statements.

Comment: @NigelRen I'm still getting the same error, see my edit.

Comment: Your missing the `end if`

Comment: @NigelRen Thank youuu! Feel free to sum up these changes in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the dialog to create a trigger in phpmyadmin, the wrapping bits of the `create trigger...` are added before applying the code.  So remove the main parts and leave the

```
if NEW.LocationId <=> OLD.LocationId or NEW.PersonId <=> OLD.PersonId THEN
     insert into history values(null, old.Id, old.LocationId, new.LocationId, old.PersonId, new.PersonId, date(now()));
end if;
```